# How can I make my website scroll down fine on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I need my WordPress website to scroll down fine on Chrome (it scrolls fine on other browser), with sections fitting the width and height of the screen each scroll.

Here is the code I used:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var win_width = jQuery(window).width();
  if (win_width <= 1300 || win_width > 1600) {
    jQuery('#fw_c').fullpage({
      anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', '3rdpage', '4thpage', 'lastPage'],
      afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index) {
        if (index == 1) {
          jQuery(".section.def_section,#header_container").removeClass('custom-shrink');
          jQuery("#section0 .rda_zoomIn").addClass("animated zoomIn");
        } else {
          jQuery(".section.def_section,#header_container").addClass('custom-shrink');
        }
        if (index == 2) {
          jQuery(".section2-title .rda_fadeInDown").addClass("animated fadeInDown");
          jQuery(".section2-body .rda_fadeInLeft").addClass("animated fadeInLeft");
        }
        if (index == 3) {
          jQuery(".section3-title .rda_fadeInDown").addClass("animated fadeInDown");
          jQuery(".section3-body .rda_fadeInLeft").addClass("animated fadeInLeft");
          jQuery(".section3-body .rda_zoomIn").addClass("animated zoomIn");
        }
        if (index == 4) {
          jQuery(".section4-title .rda_fadeInDown").addClass("animated fadeInDown");
          jQuery(".section4-body .rda_fadeInLeft").addClass("animated fadeInLeft");
          jQuery(".section3-body .rda_zoomIn").addClass("animated zoomIn");
        }
        if (index == 5) {
          jQuery(".section5-title .rda_fadeInDown").addClass("animated fadeInDown");
          jQuery(".section5-body .rda_fadeInLeft").addClass("animated fadeInLeft");
          jQuery(".section3-body .rda_zoomIn").addClass("animated zoomIn");
        }
      },
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://bluestonepools.com.au/wp-content/themes/thefox/custom_bgi/jquery.fullPage.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://bluestonepools.com.au/wp-content/themes/thefox/custom_bgi/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just edited the SmoothScroll.js file

/***************** Smooth Scrolling ******************/ if(navigator.platform.toUpperCase().indexOf('MAC') === -1 && !navigator.userAgent.match(/(Android|iPod|iPhone|iPad|IEMobile|Opera Mini)/)) {
!function(){function e(){var e=!1;e&&c("keydown",r),v.keyboardSupport&&!e&&u("keydown",r)}function t(){if(document.body){var t=document.body,n=document.documentElement,o=window.innerHeight,r=t.scrollHeight;if(S=document.compatMode.indexOf("CSS")>=0?n:t,w=t,e(),x=!0,top!=self)y=!0;else if(r>o&&(t.offsetHeight<=o||n.offsetHeight<=o)){var a=!1,i=function(){a||n.scrollHeight==document.height||(a=!0,setTimeout(function(){n.style.height=document.height+"px",a=!1},500))};if(n.style.height="auto",setTimeout(i,10),S.offsetHeight<=o){var l=document.createElement("div");l.style.clear="both",t.appendChild(l)}}v.fixedBackground||b||(t.style.backgroundAttachment="scroll",n.style.backgroundAttachment="scroll")}}function n(e,t,n,o){if(o||(o=1e3),d(t,n),1!=v.accelerationMax){var r=+new Date,a=r-C;if(a1&&(i=Math.min(i,v.accelerationMax),t*=i,n*=i)}C=+new Date}if(M.push({x:t,y:n,lastX:0>t?.99:-.99,lastY:0>n?.99:-.99,start:+new Date}),!T){var l=e===document.body,u=function(){for(var r=+new Date,a=0,i=0,c=0;c=v.animationTime,h=f?1:d/v.animationTime;v.pulseAlgorithm&&(h=p(h));var m=s.x*h-s.lastX>>0,w=s.y*h-s.lastY>>0;a+=m,i+=w,s.lastX+=m,s.lastY+=w,f&&(M.splice(c,1),c--)}l?window.scrollBy(a,i):(a&&(e.scrollLeft+=a),i&&(e.scrollTop+=i)),t||n||(M=[]),M.length?N(u,e,o/v.frameRate+1):T=!1};N(u,e,0),T=!0}}function o(e){x||t();var o=e.target,r=l(o);if(!r||e.defaultPrevented||s(w,"embed")||s(o,"embed")&&/.pdf/i.test(o.src))return!0;var a=e.wheelDeltaX||0,i=e.wheelDeltaY||0;return a||i||(i=e.wheelDelta||0),!v.touchpadSupport&&f(i)?!0:(Math.abs(a)>1.2&&(a*=v.stepSize/120),Math.abs(i)>1.2&&(i*=v.stepSize/120),n(r,-a,-i),void e.preventDefault())}function r(e){var t=e.target,o=e.ctrlKey||e.altKey||e.metaKey||e.shiftKey&&e.keyCode!==H.spacebar;if(/input|textarea|select|embed/i.test(t.nodeName)||t.isContentEditable||e.defaultPrevented||o)return!0;if(s(t,"button")&&e.keyCode===H.spacebar)return!0;var r,a=0,i=0,u=l(w),c=u.clientHeight;switch(u==document.body&&(c=window.innerHeight),e.keyCode){case H.up:i=-v.arrowScroll;break;case H.down:i=v.arrowScroll;break;case H.spacebar:r=e.shiftKey?1:-1,i=-r*c*.9;break;case H.pageup:i=.9*-c;break;case H.pagedown:i=.9*c;break;case H.home:i=-u.scrollTop;break;case H.end:var d=u.scrollHeight-u.scrollTop-c;i=d>0?d+10:0;break;case H.left:a=-v.arrowScroll;break;case H.right:a=v.arrowScroll;break;default:return!0}n(u,a,i),e.preventDefault()}function a(e){w=e.target}function i(e,t){for(var n=e.length;n--;)E[A(e[n])]=t;return t}function l(e){var t=[],n=S.scrollHeight;do{var o=E[A(e)];if(o)return i(t,o);if(t.push(e),n===e.scrollHeight){if(!y||S.clientHeight+100?1:-1,t=t>0?1:-1,(k.x!==e||k.y!==t)&&(k.x=e,k.y=t,M=[],C=0)}function f(e){if(e){e=Math.abs(e),D.push(e),D.shift(),clearTimeout(z);var t=h(D[0],120)&&h(D[1],120)&&h(D[2],120);return!t}}function h(e,t){return Math.floor(e/t)==e/t}function m(e){var t,n,o;return e*=v.pulseScale,1>e?t=e-(1-Math.exp(-e)):(n=Math.exp(-1),e-=1,o=1-Math.exp(-e),t=n+o*(1-n)),t*v.pulseNormalize}function p(e){return e>=1?1:0>=e?0:(1==v.pulseNormalize&&(v.pulseNormalize/=m(1)),m(e))}var w,g={frameRate:150,animationTime:400,stepSize:120,pulseAlgorithm:!0,pulseScale:8,pulseNormalize:1,accelerationDelta:20,accelerationMax:1,keyboardSupport:!0,arrowScroll:50,touchpadSupport:!0,fixedBackground:!0,excluded:""},v=g,b=!1,y=!1,k={x:0,y:0},x=!1,S=document.documentElement,D=[120,120,120],H={left:37,up:38,right:39,down:40,spacebar:32,pageup:33,pagedown:34,end:35,home:36},v=g,M=[],T=!1,C=+new Date,E={};setInterval(function(){E={}},1e4);var z,A=function(){var e=0;return function(t){return t.uniqueID||(t.uniqueID=e++)}}(),N=function(){return window.requestAnimationFrame||window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame||function(e,t,n){window.setTimeout(e,n||1e3/60)}}(),K=/chrome/i.test(window.navigator.userAgent),L=null;"onwheel"in document.createElement("div")?L="wheel":"onmousewheel"in document.createElement("div")&&(L="mousewheel"),L&&K&&(u(L,o),u("mousedown",a),u("load",t))}();}